# Все больше мужчин [выбирает или выбирают?] одежду

Tags: согласование, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно?

> Нашу верхнюю одежду выбирают все больше и больше мужчин.

или

> Нашу верхнюю одежду выбирает все больше и больше мужчин.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше выбрать такой вариант: **Нашу верхнюю одежду выбирает все больше и больше мужчин.**

Согласование в ед. числе связано с **препозицией сказуемого, собирательным значением подлежащего и его особым выражением.**

Сравнить: Нашу верхнюю одежду **выбирают** всё больше и больше.   Похожесть этих вариантов надо исключить.

Comment: Я не исключаю этот вариант, а просто выбираю более подходящий. Если Вы прочитаете эту тему у Розенталя, то увидите, что во многих случаях возможны оба варианта, но на выбор влияет ряд факторов.  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm